# Error in loading large(16MB) python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, trace

I created a python dictionary earlier and saved it file in text format. The size of the file is 16MB. When I try to load it using **ast**

```
f = "dictionaryInTextFile"
fileToRead = open(f, 'r')
Object = fileToRead.read()
fileToRead.close()

ObjectDict = ast.literal_eval(Object)
```

I get the following error

```
eTraceback (most recent call last):
File "somename.py", line 46, in <module>
   ObjectDict = ast.literal_eval(Object)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
   node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
   return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
File "<unknown>", line 1
```

Although when I tried to load a portion of the dictionary, it loaded successfully.

Is there a problem with the size of the dictionary or is there a some problem while parsing the dictionary from the text file and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: You seem to be missing part of the traceback.

Comment: How did you create the file? Does your code work on a smaller dictionary?

Comment: You seem to have omitted the error type and message. They are often somewhat important for diagnosing error causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a specific size limitation on dictionaries loaded by `ast.literal_eval`.

There are, however, limitations on the keys and values that the dictionary may contain. Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

I suppose that your dictionary contains something other than the above types.

As near as you can, divide your file in half, adding whatever punctuation is required to ensure that both halves are still valid dictionaries. Run `ast.literal_eval()` against both halves. If one of them raises an exception, cut it in half and repeat the process. Soon enough you'll discover the location of the problem.

Comment: Since this isn't an answer, it would have been better posted as a comment.

Comment: This certainly is an answer. Q: "Is there a problem with the size of the dictionary?" A: "No, there is not a specific size limitation on dictionaries", Q: "is there a some problem while parsing the dictionary?" A: "I suppose that your dictionary contains something other than the above types." And, edited after your comment posted, Q: "what can I do to solve it?" A: use binary search on the input file.